# How to return multiple result in nhibernate using c#

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate

I have one stored procedure which returns multiple result sets in Nhibernate using c# , below is the c# code , but I am not able to return which type because i have 3 result sets of type lure, bait and fly. so any idea on this? or i need to change code.

```
public somereturn GetData() {
    var query = _session.CreateSQLQuery("exec GetTopProducingStats 
      @userId=:userId");
    query.SetParameter("userId", userId);
    var result = _session.CreateMultiQuery()
        .Add(query.AddEntity(typeof(Lure)))
        .Add(_session.CreateSQLQuery("").AddEntity(typeof(Bait)))
        .Add(_session.CreateSQLQuery("").AddEntity(typeof(Fly)))
        .List();
}
```

Comment: What type is `result` according to the debugger? List<object>?

Comment: According debugger results is of type Ilist of array (result[0] is of type lure,result[1] is of type Bait....etc) so total 3 results..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to my comment you can make `somereturn` be IList

```
public IList GetData() {
    var query = _session.CreateSQLQuery("exec GetTopProducingStats 
      @userId=:userId");
    query.SetParameter("userId", userId);
    var result = _session.CreateMultiQuery()
        .Add(query.AddEntity(typeof(Lure)))
        .Add(_session.CreateSQLQuery("").AddEntity(typeof(Bait)))
        .Add(_session.CreateSQLQuery("").AddEntity(typeof(Fly)))
        .List();
    return result;
}
```